# How do I see the contents of a drive in Debian command line?

Tags: debian, command-line, vmware

I want to see what is on a drive so I can satisfy myself that it can be disconnected (unmounted?).
This is a vm on ESXi with 3 datastores - first is the ESXi local storage, second is a nfs share on a NAS drive (that I want to remove), third is another nfs share on a 2nd NAS drive.
I have found that the Debian vm will run fine with the 1st NAS drive disconnected from the network, but will not reboot in that state.
I assume I need to unmount the drive concerned then remove datastore2 from the ESXi server. However I don't want to do this to find I have to retrace my steps. I expect to fing that datastore2 contains nothing but redundant data that was copied to datastore3 when it was added, but I would like to be able to 'browse' it first.
Cheers,
Gordon

Answer (score 1):

See if the drive is mounted and where:

`mount`

if it is not mounted see what block devices are available to mount:

`blkid`

mount the device to a temp mount point (create the mountpoint first):

`mount /dev/sdx /mnt/temp`

check your fstab to make sure all the file systems you want to be mount are mounted:

```
cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.date
vim /etc/fstab
```